# Get text from a single element of the etree in XML

Tags: lxml, python, elementtree

The code below works fine, but isn't there any pythonic way to get the same functionality?
I just want to parse XML and get text from several elements (name, name_status, url).

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib2 import urlopen

def ask_CoL(url):
    tree = etree.parse(urlopen(url))
    tn=[ el.get('total_number_of_results') for el in tree.iter('results') ]
    try:
        nr = int(tn[0])
    except ValueError:
        nr = 0
    if nr == 1:
        newstr = str([ el.text for el in tree.getiterator(tag='name')])\
                                             .strip("[]'")+','\
                +str([ el.text for el in tree.getiterator(tag='name_status')])\
                                             .strip("[]'")+','\
                +str([ el.text for el in tree.getiterator(tag='url')])\
                                             .strip("[]'")+'\n'
    else:
        newstr = 'NA\n'
    return newstr
```

example XML:

```
<results id="" name="Theragra chalcogramma" total_number_of_results="1" number_of_results_returned="1" start="0" error_message="" version="1.6 rev 1152">
  <result>
    <id>9037795</id>
    <name>Theragra chalcogramma</name>
    <rank>Species</rank>
    <name_status>accepted name</name_status>
    <online_resource>http://www.fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?ID=318</online_resource>
    <source_database>FishBase</source_database>
    <source_database_url>http://www.fishbase.org</source_database_url>
    <name_html><i>Theragra chalcogramma</i> (Pallas, 1814)</name_html>
    <url>http://www.catalogueoflife.org/col/details/species/id/9037795</url>
  </result>
</results>
```

Comment: Do you have some sample XML?  It'll help anyone who decides to test their answers before posting.

Comment: And maybe post what you expect the output to look like too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify both interface and implementation:

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

def f(url):
    tree = etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))         
    el = tree.find('results')
    if el is not None:
       lst = [el.findtext(tag) or '' for tag in "name name_status url".split()]
       return ','.join(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you! The XML source is avaliable at baseUrl = "http://www.catalogueoflife.org/col/webservice?name="

Comment: replaced 'results' to 'result' in el = tree.find('results') and it worked perfectly.